# Disable mailhog in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, email, homestead

I have :

- Vagrant
- Laravel Homestead

I set up basic registration and email verification.
Email driver :

- "sendmail"

Emails do not reach the addressee because mailhog intercepts them.
How to disable mailhog temporarily?

**Added:**

Vagrant mail log:

```
homestead postfix/pickup[8133]: 0EE1343FBD: uid=1000 from=<mail@xxx.com>
Aug 29 10:11:20 homestead postfix/cleanup[8945]: 0EE1343FBD: message-id=<7c4185afa2aeef4270219f174dc15132@xxx>
Aug 29 10:11:20 homestead postfix/qmgr[2315]: 0EE1343FBD: from=<mail@xxx.com>, size=9108, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 29 10:11:20 homestead postfix/smtp[8947]: 0EE1343FBD: to=<xxx@gmail.com>, relay=localhost[127.0.0.1]:1025, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as JKuIakBJQQYcZ65KGJ44vpWGdhG2CDfygMb5ueL1e1Q=@mailhog.example)
Aug 29 10:11:20 homestead postfix/qmgr[2315]: 0EE1343FBD: removed
```

Comment: Make sure the ```sendmail``` path is correct? The default path is ```/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs``` and make sure you have setup the correct mail driver on your .env file

Comment: Yes. I write path from php.ini

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily disable MailHog and allow your emails to be sent through the "sendmail" driver, you can follow these steps:

1. SSH into your Homestead Vagrant box by navigating to your project folder and running:

   ```
   vagrant ssh
   ```
2. Locate the MailHog service and stop it. MailHog typically runs on port 1025, so you can stop it using the following command:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop mailhog
   ```
3. After stopping MailHog, you can try sending an email again from your Laravel application. This time, the email should not be intercepted by MailHog and should be sent out through the "sendmail" driver.
4. Verify that the emails are now being sent by checking the mail log. Based on the log you provided, it seems like the email was sent successfully, as indicated by the "status=sent" message:

   ```
   Aug 29 10:11:20 homestead postfix/smtp[8947]: 0EE1343FBD: to=<xxx@gmail.com>, relay=localhost[127.0.0.1]:1025, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as JKuIakBJQQYcZ65KGJ44vpWGdhG2CDfygMb5ueL1e1Q=@mailhog.example)
   ```
5. Once you have verified that the emails are being sent correctly, you can start MailHog again if you wish to use it for testing or debugging email-related issues in the future. To start MailHog, run the following command:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start mailhog
   ```

With MailHog temporarily disabled, your emails should now reach their intended recipients without interception. Remember to re-enable MailHog when you want to use it for testing email functionality in your Laravel application.

Answer (score -1):

You can stop the service with => brew services stop mailhog

Comment: There is no information about OS. Nothing to do with a brew

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).